# Unable to import pyspark in dataproc cluster on GCP

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I just setup a cluster on Google Cloud Platform to run some pyspark jobs.
Initially I used ipython.sh (from the github repository) as initialization script for the cluster. This allowed the cluster to startup nicely, however when trying to import pyspark in an Ipython notebook, I got a "cannot import name accumulators" error.

After some searching, I was thinking this had something to do with the install path for pyspark not being included in my Python Path, so I deleted my cluster and wanted to create a new one, using jupyter.sh, as initialization script.

However, now my cluster wont startup at all, I get an error.
Checking the log "dataproc-initialization-script-0_output" it simply says:

/usr/bin/env: bash
: No such file or directory

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

---

**Edit:**

I got the cluster to start with the public initialization script in gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh

However, I'm still running into the same issues when trying to load pyspark in a pyspark notebook, 
when I try something like "from pyspark import SparkConf"
I get errors (weirdly enough, I get a different error if I run the same import a second time).

Any feedback at this stage?

This is the output of my notebook:
[html notebook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnA03.png)

Comment: Do you have a cluster_uuid or an operation_id you can share either here or privately with dataproc-feedback@google.com?

Comment: The cluster_uuids are:  `cluster-1:192c22e4-e0f6-4970-8428-687327016c49` and `cluster-1:a1218d27-1b5a-4c7f-97ec-71b34cf76b5f`, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The most recent Jupyter initialization action for Dataproc was created to target Dataproc `--image-version 1.0`, so the change of default version to `1.1` which includes Spark 2.0.0 appears to have silently broken the PySpark kernel (unfortunately, instead of erroring out during deployment, the PySpark kernel simply fails to create the correct Spark environment).

A generous contributor actually [did send a pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/71) awhile ago when Dataproc 1.1 was just about to become the default, but during review, Dataproc team wanted to refactor the script for better future-proofing without keeping separate forks of the kernel configs explicitly.

I went ahead and whipped up the [refactoring pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/75) which allows a base kernel generator to work against both Dataproc 1.0 and Dataproc 1.1. As soon as that's merged, new clusters using the standard `gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh` will automatically start to work correctly. In the meantime, you can do one of two things:

1. Try reverting to Dataproc 1.0 / Spark 1.6.2:

   ```
   gcloud dataproc clusters create --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
       --image-version 1.0
   ```
2. Try out my updates in-place (and thus keep the freshest Dataproc 1.1 + Spark 2.0.0) before it's merged into the upstream master:

   ```
   gcloud dataproc clusters create --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
       --metadata INIT_ACTIONS_REPO=https://github.com/dennishuo/dataproc-initialization-actions.git,INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH=dhuo-fix-jupyter-spark2
   ```

Comment: FYI this was merged and synced up to GCS yesterday, so new clusters created with just `gcloud dataproc clusters create --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh` should work fine now.